# Problem with equation numbering

Tags: equations, hyperref, numbering, refcheck

I'm writing my thesis using latex. I get a problem with equation numbering an

[image: Additional barket including interrogation point appears.]
[Attached my thesis](http://www.filedropper.com/tstcorrection). I need your helps please

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcheck}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{equ1}
H(x)=w^T+b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please create a minimal working example. Nobody is going to download your entire thesis, especially given the need to enter a captcha and unpack a rar file. (Yes, I did go to have a look.)

Comment: I have uploaded the entire thesis because the problem is due to the thesis style. The problem appears just with my thesis, when I use an article style I can get equation numbering correctly without problem

Comment: Against my better judgment, I went and had a look (guess I am having a slow day). The problem appears with the article class too. I am going to edit your question now, adding a minimal working example.

Comment: thank for your example :) I have complicated the task with my long question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost the intended result of the `refhcheck` package. I say almost, for instead of {?} you should be seeing `?equ1?` in its place, indicating the label for that equation. But the `hyperref` package messes that up for you. You can just do

```
\usepackage[noref]{refcheck}
```

or just live with this output, but remember to remove the `refcheck` package before creating the final version of your thesis.

Comment: (By the way, you included the `reftex` package twice.)

Comment: Thanks a lot the problem is due to the refhcheck package